# no module named res_rc after compile res.qrc file using pyrrc5.exe

Tags: pyqt5, pyuic, pyrcc

With Qt Creator I created a `.ui` file and set the main window icon referred to a `.ico` in `res.qrc` file.
Then in PyCharm I used `pyuic`&`pyrcc` to convert qt files to `.py` files.
However  after I start up my app, I got an import error saying that `No module named res_rc` in converted ui.py.
I don't know why this time I got the import error. Before today I could really use `res_rc.py` in my severval pyqt5 examples .
Did I miss something that vital ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that files like `res_rc.py` and `ui.py` should be in the same folder with `app.py`  and now it works fine.
Previously I put `res_rc.py` and `ui.py` in a sub folder

Answer (score 0):

ui is looking for your res_rc.py in the root folder and you may have saved it somewhere else.
There are 2 solutions: move the file to the root of the program or in the ui.py file change the import to "yourmodule.res_rc.py'